# In C++, what return type to use when the template is variable?

Tags: c++

In the code snippet below, what should I put as the template for `MyOtherClass` in the return type of the `MyClass::create`` function  ?

To make it easier, I can make A , B, C classes all inherit a common class.

And is there a more elegant way of doing this?

```
template<class MyTemplateClass>
class MyOtherClass{
  //
};

class MyClass{
   public: 
     MyOtherClass<//What do I put here?>
     MyClass::create(const std::string& input){
       if (input == "a"){
         return MyOtherClass<A>(); //A is a class
       }
       if (input == "b"){
         return MyOtherClass<B>(); // B is a class
       }
       return MyOtherClass<C>(); // C is a class
     }
};
```

Comment: It's not possible. The return type must be known at compile-time. The arguments to a function are not compile-time expressions, therefore it's not possible.

Comment: The return type of a function must be known at compile-time.  You can not write a function that decides at runtime what type it returns.

Comment: Also, `if (input == 'a') ...` won't work: You can't compare a `std::string` to a single `char`.

Comment: @local-ninja what if i make A,B,C classes all inherit a common class ?

Comment: *What do I put here?* You can have the return type be `std::variant<MyOtherClass<A>, MyOtherClass<B>, MyOtherClass<C>>`.

Comment: @user1008636 Yes, that's possible. You can use run-time polymorphism or some other alternatives (as listed by Lopez' answer).

Comment: the fact that the classes are instantiations of the same template is almost irrelevant. You'd have the same issue if the classes to be returned were `X`,`Y` and `Z`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is, you can't as is.

You can do something like this either through inheritance (A, B and C inherits from a common base class),
or with std::variant, or with type erasure (MyOtherClass inherits from something)

The question is more about how do you plan on using what comes out of the function?

Comment: So I can make A,B,C all inherit from a common base class, and make `create` return  MyOtherClass<BaseClass> ?

Comment: Well, that depends what MyOtherClass does with the type, but that could be an option yeah